# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file when stripping file

Tags: python-3.x

The following snipet of code results in this error:
 ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

```
            file = open("Groups.txt", 'r')
            lineList = [line.strip() for line in file]

            choice2 = choicebox("Which group would you like to add the children to?", "Choose a group.",
                                choices=lineList)
            file.close()

            file1 = open('%s.txt' % choice2, 'a')
            file.write(str(file1) + "\n")
            file.close()
```

Comment: `lineList` contains the lines from `Groups.txt` with the newlines intact. Hence you also get those in `choice2` and it seems `\n` isn't a valid character for filenames on your OS.

Comment: I've tried several ways of stripping this but still get the same error.

Comment: Show us how you stripped this so we can help you figure it out.

Comment: where in the code is the \n character added to the filename? that's what confuses me.

Comment: @sleepylog `file.readlines()` returns the lines *including* the line delimiter... Consider using `lineList = [line.strip() for line in file]` instead

Comment: Thank you Jon Clements, this is what I wrote but now i get a ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. file = open("Groups.txt", 'r')
                lineList = [line.strip() for line in file]

                choice2 = choicebox("Which group would you like to add the children to?", "Choose a group.",
                                    choices=lineList)
                file.close()

                file1 = open('%s.txt' % choice2, 'a')
                file.write(str(file1) + "\n")
                file.close()

Comment: @sleepylog That's because you now open `file1`, but still refer to `file` in  `file.write()` (and `file` is already closed).

Comment: haha! been at this too long and my brain is shutting down. Thank you! It worked and my script is once again running.